# Run Github Action on two self-hosted machines with matrix and max-parallel setup

Tags: github, github-actions

In my env I have two self-hosted machines:

1. OrangePi ARM
2. Graviton3 ARM

I have plenty of long running scenarios to be executed on those two (it may take even weeks to complete) - in total 18 jobs per machine split into matrix like below:

```yaml
jobs:
  build-and-run:
    timeout-minutes: 2880
    strategy:
      max-parallel: 2
      fail-fast: true
      matrix:
        os: [orangePi, Graviton3]
        client-network: [
          { client: "client1", network: "network1" },
          { client: "client2", network: "network2" },
          ...
          { client: "client18", network: "network18" }
    ]
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
```

It works well when `max-parallel` is not set (triggers job on two agents in same time) but issue is - after 24h all jobs which wasn't successful to be started are marked as failed with error:

> This request was automatically failed because there were no enabled runners online to process the request for more than 1 days.

`max-parallel` seems to solve that because job is started but is not acquiring or waiting in queue for any agent. But downside is, with such approach, on my list I have 18 jobs of orangePi followed by 18job with Graviton. Because of that `max-parallel` tries to start first two orangePi and is not utilizing Graviton agent.

### Question is:

Any idea how to start workflow which will utilize both agents to speed up action AND do not timeout others after 24h?
I think I can split them into two separate workflow but I feel like it may be a bit hacky having two exact same workflows with just different agent (I need to maintain both which may lead to something missed in one of those - I don't like to repeat myself).

Tried various params, values for max-parallel or ordering but everything fails as for now.

Comment: Have you tried switching the order of the matrix parameters? `client-network` and `os` in the YAML?

Comment: According to [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/managing-self-hosted-runners/about-self-hosted-runners#usage-limits) the 24 hour limit can't be helped with. But as for triggering both agents at the same time when you have max parallel, swapping the order of the two parameters in the matrix would probably do as said by the previous commenter.

Comment: Ahh thanks guys! 
Wasn't aware that it may affect selection :D 
And max-parallel seems also to do the trick since it is not allocating agent so job is not started but this is still under checking.